# Primefaces p:dialog modal="true" appendToBody it´s not working

Tags: primefaces, dialog, modal-dialog, append

I tried many things for this workaround, but now I found a issue with p:dialog.
If I use modal="false" everything works fine.
But if I use modal="true" and appendTo="@(body)" and want to use a footer the p:dialog doesnt work.
The h:form doesn´t validate the fields.

```
     <p:dialog message="Add Ticket" header="Add Ticket"
                draggable="true" resizable="true" closeOnEscape="true"
                appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" widgetVar="addTicketReportingDialog">
<h:form id="addTicketReportingForm">
                <h:panelGrid id="ticketReportingAddPanelGrid" columns="2">

                   <p:outputLabel for="ticketReporting_name" value="Name:" />
                   <p:inputText id="ticketReporting_name" size="33" required="true"
                      requiredMessage="Please add a value"
                      value="#{ticketReportingEditController.ticketReporting.title}" />

                </h:panelGrid>

                <br></br>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                   <p:commandButton value="Save"
                      oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) addTicketReportingDialog.hide()"
                      update=":ticketReportingListForm:ticketReportingListDatatable,messagesAddTicketReporting,:addTicketReportingForm:ticketReportingAddPanelGrid"
                      actionListener="#{ticketReportingEditController.doSave}"
                      ajax="true" />

                   <h:outputText value=" or " />

                   <p:commandLink ajax="true" process="@this"
                      onclick="addTicketReportingDialog.hide();">
                      <h:outputText value="Close" />
                   </p:commandLink>

                   <p:messages id="messagesAddTicketReporting" showDetail="false"
                      for="messagesAddTicketReporting" autoUpdate="false"
                      closable="true" />
                </f:facet>
     </h:form>
             </p:dialog>
```

Comment: does it have to be a dialog? it seems to me that a overlaypanel could do it?